# I can't figure out how to set the proper indexes for MySQL subqueries

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(d_source,"TOTAL") AS SOURCE
    , IFNULL(SUM(STORECOUNT),0) AS STORECOUNT
    , IFNULL(SUM(STORECOUNTCP),0) AS STORECOUNTCP
    , IFNULL(SUM(TDP),0) AS TDP
    , IFNULL(SUM(TDPCP),0) AS TDPCP
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(TDP) / SUM(STORECOUNT),2),0) AS AVGUPCSPERSTORE
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(TDPCP) / SUM(STORECOUNTCP),2),0) AS AVGUPCSPERSTORECP
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(TOTAL) / SUM(STORECOUNT) / 8.57,2),0) AS AVGUNITSPERSTORE
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CPTOTAL) / SUM(STORECOUNTCP) / 4.29,2),0) AS AVGUNITSPERSTORECP
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(TOTAL),0),0) AS TOTAL
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(CPTOTAL),0),0) AS CPTOTAL
    , IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(PPTOTAL),0),0) AS PPTOTAL
    ,  ROUND(sum(2016_Apr),0) AS 2016_Apr , ROUND(sum(2016_May),0) AS 2016_May  
FROM (
    SELECT d_source
        ,key_retailer
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-05-31' AND unit_sales > 0 THEN store_id  END)) STORECOUNT
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31' AND unit_sales > 0 THEN store_id END)) STORECOUNTCP
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-05-31' AND unit_sales > 0 THEN CONCAT(upc,store_id) END)) TDP
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31' AND unit_sales > 0 THEN CONCAT(upc,store_id) END)) TDPCP
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-05-31' THEN unit_sales  ELSE 0 END) TOTAL
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31' THEN unit_sales  ELSE 0 END) CPTOTAL
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30' THEN unit_sales  ELSE 0 END) PPTOTAL
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-04-30' THEN unit_sales ELSE 0 END) 2016_Apr 
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-05-01' AND '2016-05-31' THEN unit_sales ELSE 0 END) 2016_May  
    FROM storeCheckRecords   
        INNER JOIN allStores ON allStores.id = store_id  
    WHERE d_source !='STORELOCATOR' 
    GROUP BY d_source
    ) T 
GROUP BY d_source WITH ROLLUP
```

And here is the explain:

```
id  s_type   table       type   p_keys    key     key_len  ref      rows         Extra
1   PRIMARY  <derived2>  ALL    NULL      NULL    NULL     NULL     2            Using filesort
2   DERIVED  SCR         ALL    store_id  NULL    NULL     NULL     1229950      Using where; Using filesort
2   DERIVED allStores    eq_ref PRIMARY   PRIMARY 4        dfc.SCR  1            Using where
```

I don't understand what I am missing to stop the search of the entire SCR table and or index it so that it doesn't search all.  Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Can you post create table syntax for relevant tables?

Comment: As far as I know, indexes are not used for `!=` conditions; I would think your best bet would be to index `datetimesql` and add `AND datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-05-31'` to your subquery's where clause.

Comment: Hi Neil, there are a lot of columns and it is a big create statement.  Anything you are looking for specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip Uueerdo, but it still didn't use the index datetimesql.  This query is taking over 30 seconds! ouch!

Comment: You have/added an index on datetimesql, right? If so, maybe move the `d_source != 'STORELOCATOR'` into a HAVING after the subquery's group by

Comment: I wrote it this way and it is faster, but it is still not using the index: `INNER JOIN allStores 
          ON allStores.id = store_id WHERE datetimesql BETWEEN '2016-04-01' AND '2016-05-31' GROUP BY d_source HAVING d_source !='STORELOCATOR'`

Comment: And you have added, or confirmed the existence of, an index on only (or starting with) that field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115348/discussion-between-damon-and-uueerdo).